# Problem with [DefaultValue()] inheriting ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

for a project of mine I inherited a ComboBox to change its size behaviour. In addition to this i wanted, to speed up my forms' creation, to set the default `DropDownStyle` to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`

To do this i used the `[Default()]` command overwriting the `DropDownStyle` property

```
[DefaultValue(ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList)]
public new ComboBoxStyle DropDownStyle
{
    get
    {
        return base.DropDownStyle;
    }
    set
    {
        base.DropDownStyle = value;
    }
}
```

Then i modified the default value in the Designer setting the `DropDownStyle` to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`.

And here comes the problem...
There is a small number of InheritedComboBox which i want to have `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown` because they need to work with

```
AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.Append;
AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
```

If i set it from the Designer it works fine, however, sometimes, after i rebuild the form, it throws an exception (also at design time) regarding the ComboBoxStyle. When i look to the FormName.Designer.cs file, i can find that for the specific InheritedComboBox there is no

`DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDown`

and I have to add it manually.
This is a little boring because sometimes i just notice it at runtime, when the program throws an exception without showing the form and i cannot test every form every time i rebuild...

Do you have any idea why i get this strange behaviour?

Is there any way to fix it?

Thanks a lot for any answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the `AutoCompleteMode` or `AutoCompleteSource` property, I believe the designer is looking to the base ComboBox and not generating the line to set the `DropDownStyle`, since `DropDown` *is* the default value for ComboBox.

I was able to correct this by adding an `AutoCompleteMode` and `AutoCompleteSource` property to the inherited ComboBox, but also had to add in a line to set the base `DropDownStyle` because of the order in which the designer sets the properties.

Try something like this and see if it works for you:

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.None;
        AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.None;
    }

    [DefaultValue(ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList)]
    public new ComboBoxStyle DropDownStyle
    {
        get { return base.DropDownStyle; }
        set { base.DropDownStyle = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue(AutoCompleteMode.None)]
    public new AutoCompleteMode AutoCompleteMode
    {
        get { return base.AutoCompleteMode; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != AutoCompleteMode.None)
                base.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;

            base.AutoCompleteMode = value; 
        }
    }
    [DefaultValue(AutoCompleteSource.None)]
    public new AutoCompleteSource AutoCompleteSource
    {
        get { return base.AutoCompleteSource; }
        set 
        {
            if (value != AutoCompleteSource.None)
                base.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;

            base.AutoCompleteSource = value; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works! I noticed that in fact, the DropDownStyle properties is set by the designer, but after the AutoComplete (it seems to be alphabetically). Probably it works fine for the original ComboBox because the DropDown is the default. I wonder if there is any way to affect the order in which the properties are assigned by the designer.. i tried to search but i didn't find anything.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you.  I also looked for some way to change the order (looked for an attribute), but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this value to the property in the constructor of the inherited combobox too to the value you set with DefaultValue. This should probably fix your issue.

Comment: No, unfortunately this didn't help

Comment: The problem you describe does sound a lot like this would be the issue. .NET gets confused when the DefaultValue and the value set by the constructor are out of sync. Try deleting the assignment from Designer.cs, set it again in the property list and see if that helps.

Comment: The problem is that VS delete it on his own, and i always have to write it manually again. I also tried to delete it and set it again in designer or manually, but this did not work.

Comment: Whey you add the inherited control to the form, what does the value in the property list shows? Also, is it bold?